# Can you change the picture in a gui with a button press? (Python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am working on a picture thing, and I want the user to be able to select an image with buttons. But instead, nothing changes. How do you do that?

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
n = 0
x = 0
def func(n):
    is_ = [
        Image.open(r"image_file1.png"),
        Image.open(r"image_file2.png"),
        Image.open(r"image_file3.png")
    ]
    global x
    x = n
    i2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(is_[x])
    c2.create_image(50, 50, image = i2)
    
root = tk.Tk()
i = Image.open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\0mega.patch\2. Python\LucasPatrykRiley\Pfps\Clear Background.png")
i2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(i)


c = tk.Canvas(root, height = 600, width = 600)
c.pack()

f = tk.Frame(root)

c2 = tk.Canvas(f, height = 100, width = 100, bg = "Blue")
c2.create_image(50, 50, image = i2)
c2.pack()

b = tk.Button(f, text = ">", command = func(x + 1))
b.pack()

b2 = tk.Button(f, text = "<", command = func(x - 1))
b2.pack()


c.create_window(200, 500, window = f)

root.mainloop()
```

`is_` is the list of all images;
`x` is the user choice which gets updated so you can take the previous / next image;
`c` is the canvas where everything is positioned. I chose canvas bc the canvas can contain images.
This is a snippet of the main file, where the canvas has an image of the actual background.
The widgets are packed into the f Frame, which get placed into the c canvas

How can I make the images change with the button press?

Comment: Why do You ask `can` and not `how` because in vast majority of cases the answer to `can` is YES. And so in this case. The answer to _Can you change the picture in a gui with a button press?_ is YES. Anyhow does this answer Your question: [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Comment: Just so You know, Labels and Buttons can too contain images. And I think it would be actually maybe easier to change an image for a label than canvas

Comment: The issue: You create all the images in a function and when the function is done that list that contained all those images gets garbage collected and since no reference was created it all gets deleted. See previous comment for a similar issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

> Can you change the picture in a gui with a button press?

> the user choice which gets updated so you can take the previous / next
> image

The `func(n)` function doesn't do anything.

The problem can be fixed and easier way to do.

- On line 4, add `list_images` are used to store multiple items in a
  single variable.
- On line 5, add declare index variable.
- Create two function for previous and next.
- Add `c.itemconfig` for updating previous and next
  functions.
- On line 31, uncertainty your path `Image.open`.

Snippet modified:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

list_images = ["image_file1.png", "image_file2.png", "image_file3.png", "image_file4.png"]
index: int = 0

def next_image():
    global index, show_image
    if index == len(list_images)-1:
        return
    index += 1
    show_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=list_images[index])
    c.itemconfig(image_canvas, image=show_image)

def previous_image():
    global index, show_image
    if index == 0:
        return
    index -= 1
    show_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=list_images[index])
    c.itemconfig(image_canvas, image=show_image)    
     
root = tk.Tk()

c = tk.Canvas(root, height = 200, width = 600)

show_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=list_images[index])
image_canvas = c.create_image(90, 50, image=show_image)
c.pack()

i = Image.open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\0mega.patch\2. Python\LucasPatrykRiley\Pfps\Clear Background.png")
i2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(i)

f = tk.Frame(root)

c2 = tk.Canvas(root, height = 100, width =120, bg="Blue")
c2.create_image(60,50, image = i2)
c2.pack()

b = tk.Button(root, text=">", command=next_image)
 
b2 = tk.Button(root, text="<", command=previous_image)
 
b2.pack()
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot for next and previous button:

[image]